# how to pull all records in hive based on another column

Tags: sql, hive, hql, hiveql

If this is what my table looks like below:

```
my_id       my_words               my_people     my_number
100       need more info?            Jim           1
100       now                        Mary          2
100       what's that?               Jim           3
101       okay now                   Jim           1
101       sounds good                Mary          2
102       still hungry?              Jim           1
102       now I'm thirsty though     Mary          2
102       I don't understand         Jim           3
102       no I'm not hungry          Mary          4
103       are you there?             Jim           1
103       I don't know               Mary          2
103       That's okay                Jim           3
```

How can I get this output?

```
my_id       my_words               my_people     my_number
100       need more info?            Jim           1
100       now                        Mary          2
100       what's that?               Jim           3
102       still hungry?              Jim           1
102       Now I'm thirsty though     Mary          2
102       I don't understand         Jim           3
```

right now I have: SELECT my_id, my_words, my_people, my_number from table where my_people="Mary" AND lower(my_words) like 'now%';

But I don't only want to return those rows, I also want to return Jim's comment right before and right after Mary's (before/after based on my_number column)

Maybe this is unrelated, but ultimately, I'm going to want this in Excel with this format:

```
my_id       Jim_words           Mary_words                 Jim_next_words
100      need more info?           now                      what's that?
102       still hungry?     now I'm thirsty though       I don't understand
```

Comment: which database is this supposed to run - hive or mysql ? both are different dbs

Comment: also, can there be many `my_people`, data ? like what if john, jane,Wag21 shows up in that column?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @KoushikRoy this is for hive. Maybe I should remove the mysql tag. my_people only has two distinct values for entire dataset

Comment: Sorry to ask, can there be Jim's next nect words ? or Jims next, next next words ? I am trying to see how many columns you are going to have in XL. we can generate data like XL expected output easily.

Comment: @KoushikRoy there's no need to be sorry - I'm happy for any help, as I am a hive beginner in past two weeks. Some of these conversations have my_number >100 even. However, I ONLY want Jim's words right before Mary says "now%" and Jim's words right after Mary says "now%"

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try below code? Code has explanations as comment.

```
WITH cte as (SELECT my_id, my_words, my_people, my_number 
row_number() over( partition by my_id order by my_number) as rn --giving a unique row number for a my id 
from table)
SELECT 
distinct mytab.my_id, chosentab.my_words jims_words, mytab.my_people, mytab.my_number,
case when case when lower(mytab.my_words) like 'now%' then mytab.rn+1 end  = chosentab.rn then chosentab.my_words end jims_words_after_marys_now,
case when case when lower(mytab.my_words) like 'now%' then mytab.rn-1 end  = chosentab.rn then chosentab.my_words end jims_words_before_marys_now
FROM 
cte mytab,
cte chosentab
where
mytab.my_id=chosentab.my_id and
case when lower(mytab.my_words) like 'now%' then mytab.rn+1 end  = chosentab.rn and   -- selecting jims rows where mary said now after jim 
case when lower(mytab.my_words) like 'now%' then mytab.rn-1 end  = chosentab.rn  -- selecting jims rows where mary said now before jim
```

Now I created the SQL based on our discussion. Could you please validate and let me know it if worked?

Comment: hmmm...I am getting "FAILED: ParseException line 1:93 extraneous input '(' expecting ) near ')' in statement (state=42000, code=40000).

Comment: I will check tomorrow. Thnks for trying.

Comment: No rush, this relates to something I was working on at work but not a priority. I am mainly just trying to learn more. I was wondering if "case when case when" was supposed to be repeated like that. I'm sure it is, as I am new at this, but it seemed odd to me.